# Convert hierarchical list to a flat list in java

Tags: java, list, recursion

I have a hierarchical `list` like below and I want to convert it to a flat `list`.

I have wrote a method called `convertToFlatList` and have used it. But some elements are missing in the final results. What did i do wrong?

Also is there a better way than the way I have used to convert my list to a flat list?

I have added a sample code and something similar to the Objects I have to used in my scenario. Final result should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Member memberOne = new Member(1);
    Member memberTwo = new Member(2);
    Member memberThree = new Member(3);
    Member memberFour = new Member(4);
    Member memberFive = new Member(5);
    Member memberSix = new Member(6);
    Member memberSeven = new Member(7);

    memberTwo.setChildren(Arrays.asList(memberThree, memberFour));
    memberFour.setChildren(Arrays.asList(memberFive, memberSix));

    List<Member> memberList = Arrays.asList(memberOne, memberTwo, memberSeven);
    List<Member> flatList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Member> convertedList = convertToFlatList(memberList, flatList);
    System.out.println(convertedList);
  }

  private static List<Member> convertToFlatList(List<Member> memberList, List<Member> flatList)
  {
    for (Member member : memberList)
    {
      if (member.getChildren() != null)
      {
        convertToFlatList(member.getChildren(), flatList);
      }
      else
      {
        flatList.add(member);
      }
    }
    return flatList;
  }
}

class Member
{
  private List<Member> children;

  private int memberId;

  Member(int memberId)
  {
    this.memberId = memberId;
  }

  List<Member> getChildren()
  {
    return children;
  }

  void setChildren(List<Member> children)
  {
    this.children = children;
  }

  int getMemberId()
  {
    return memberId;
  }

  void setMemberId(int memberId)
  {
    this.memberId = memberId;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.valueOf(this.memberId);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `flatList.add(member);` always not only when `Member` has no children

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a `Member` has children, you correctly add the children to the flattened list, but miss the `Member` itself. Just move the addition of the member outside of the `else` block add you should be fine:

```
private static List<Member> 
convertToFlatList(List<Member> memberList, List<Member> flatList)
{
    for (Member member : memberList)
    {
        // Always add the member to flatList
        flatList.add(memeber);

        // If it has children, add them toore
        if (member.getChildren() != null)
        {
            convertToFlatList(member.getChildren(), flatList);
        }
    }
    return flatList;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use Java 8, just add this method to the `Member` class:

```
public Stream<Member> streamAll(){
    if(getChildren() == null){
        return Stream.of(this);
    }
    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(this), getChildren().stream().flatMap(Member::streamAll));
}
```

Alternatively, you can remove the null check if you always initialize `children` to an empty list :

```
public Stream<Member> streamAll(){
    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(this), getChildren().stream().flatMap(Member::streamAll));
}
```

Then to get the flat list:

```
List<Member> convertedList = memberList.stream()
                                       .flatMap(Member::streamAll)
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Lets say children are always initialize to an empty list. In recursion, its terminated when a certain conditions are met. How is that working on your second one? It works there. Just want to understand how it works

Comment: If children is an empty list, then `getChildren().stream().flatMap(Member::streamAll))` returns and an empty stream and then the concatenation of `Stream.of(this)` and an empty stream is simply `Stream.of(this)`.

Answer (score 2):

Do this by using java-8 `flatMap` and recursion

> Change `convertToFlatList` method to take only one argument (i,e `List<Member>`)

If `getChildren()` is not `null`, then do the recursion or else return the current object

```
private static List<Member> convertToFlatList(List<Member> memberList)
  {
       return memberList.stream().flatMap(i->{
          if(Objects.nonNull(i.getChildren())) {
             return Stream.concat(Stream.of(i), convertToFlatList(i.getChildren()).stream());
          }
          return Stream.of(i);

      }).collect(Collectors.toList());

  }
```

**Output :**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is the problem of level/recursive order traversal of a tree. Here is detail of the problem and solutions:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

By the way, this is traversal (Depth first-Pre order) of your problem:

```
static class Member {
  List<Member> children = new ArrayList<>();
  int id;
  boolean visit = false;
}
public List<Member> printList(Member member) {
  Stack<Member> stack =  new Stack<>();
  List<Member> list =  new ArrayList<>();
  stack.push(member);
  while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
    Member node = stack.pop();
    list.add(node);
    for(Member m: node.children) {
    stack.push(m);
    }
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't agree. If you use a Stack (LIFO) or recursive methods, it's a DFS. If you use a Queue (FIFO), it's a BFS.

Comment: @Ricola the question is not about the traversal and approaches, but about the list of tree nodes. In fact this example code is Depth-first (in pre-order) mode. For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order

Comment: I totally agree, it was just a response to @BoristheSpider who deleted his comment